# Is it possible to earn individual medals of the same type multiple times in mass effect 3 multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In the Mass Effect 3 multiplayer you can earn individual medals for things like number of kills.  These medals are divided into bronze, silver and gold levels - in the case of kills these correspond to 25, 50 and 75 kills.

My question is whether it is possible to earn multiple medals of the same kind during a game?

i.e. if I get to 100 kills do I get a gold and bronze medal for kills or just a single gold medal for reaching the 75 kills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Bronze, Silver and Gold in a single game and then once again in another game.
If you got 100 kills in a single game you would get the Bronze Medal first and then you would get the Silver Medal, Still retaining the Bronze, You would then get Gold while still retaining Bronze and Silver.

You can only get one of each medal per match.

Comment: The one exception to this is the survival streak. You can get a silver medal for surviving five rounds, have a casualty in the sixth, and then survive three rounds straight and wind up with a silver and a bronze medal.

Comment: @Shadur Good point though that is a team rather than individual medal

Comment: Yah. And as far as I'm aware, it's the only exception.

Comment: The survival medals would mean that if you got the bronze and silver then someone died then you had no deaths then you would get the bronze again while keeping the previous bronze and silver, this is the only exception as far as i am aware of :)